# Call API resource using meteor

Tags: reactjs, rest, meteor, meteor-react

I would like to call an API resource using meteor and React. What I would like to happen is;

1. load a page
2. have a form shown to a user
3. user submits form
4. use the form data as parameters for the API call via POST
5. returns the API response to React.

How do I achieve this? Am I on the right track by using Meteor.wrapAsync?

Answer (score 1):

Meteor.wrapAsync wouldn't be neccesary. If you have a button in React. You should keep the fields in the state. [React Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html). Then use this code in your component to call a meteor method.

```
onClick(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const { objectToPost } = this.state;
  Meteor.call("some_method", objectToPost, (err, res) => { doSmthWithFrontend });
}
```

The Meteor method will be called async for you and return when the call returns. In this method you can use [Meteor Http](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html) to achieve what you want.

Comment: hi, what's the proper way to return the "res" variable? I always get undefined when I try to log it

Comment: return a value in your method. If a Meteor method returns a value it is placed in the second parameter. If the methods throws an error it is returned in the first parameter